# how to printout help text using getopt in C?

Tags: c, getopt

I have a question about use getopt with command with the following code:

```
void createFunction()
{
   printf("create function\n");
}

void printHelp()
{
   printf("print help info\n");
}

const struct option long_opts[] = {{"help", no_argument, NULL, HELP},
                                   {"c",    no_argument ,NULL, CREATE_OPTION},
                                   {NULL,   0,           NULL, 0}};

while((opt = getopt_long_only(argc, argv, "", long_opts, NULL)) != -1)
{
    switch(opt) {
        case HELP:
            printHelp();
            break;
        case CREATE_OPTION:
            createFunction();
            break;
        default:
            printf("type base --help for details\n");
    }
}
```

how to printout the help text when type command without any parameters or with any faulty parameters,
for example: only type command(in my case is `"base"`) to trigger a printout of the help text? or command `"base --"` will trigger help text? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use '?' case to trigger when an unrecognized option is passed :

```
case '?':
    printf("Unknown option `-%c'.\n", optopt);
    printHelp();
    break;
```

Comment: are there any ways I can add "?" to the long_opts[]?

Comment: You don't need to add it, getopt will automatically return it if the option is unrecognized.

Comment: I added as what you said, but when I build it, it says:error: case label does not reduce to an integer constant